# Is it possible to manually run one browser and have the commands copied to other browsers?

Tags: manual-testing, testing-environment

I'd love to jump right in and start writing Selenium tests but this is more of a manual situation because adding tests would be a whole thing that I don't have time for. Is there a way to manually interact with one browser (IE) and as you do things the commands are copied to other browsers (Edge, Chrome) so you can see in real time how a website behaves in three browsers without having to write any code?

Perhaps it would be a hacktastic Selenium IDE solution? Perhaps it would be an OS level thing where you mirror mouse and keyboard events to each monitor? Perhaps it could be done with a VM?

Comment: Note: When you don't have time for the quality approach, don't expect good quality or be surprised when other approaches fail to produce it.  High quality is hard.

Answer (score 1):

With the tool BrowseEmAll (https://browseemall-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#browser-compare) you can test manual in multiple browsers at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Since Selenium IDE is a browser extension, it's reach is limited to the perticular browser within which it is installed.

Hence, you may not be able to run the same script simultaneously in multiple browsers.

The best you can do with Selenium IDE is record your tests in one browser, save the project and then in the other browser open that same project and run your test.

If you want to run parallel tests in multiple browsers, I guess it would be a good idea to use multi-threading with Selenium Webdriver. Where you write your code once. Create Classes and Methods with OOPS and then run multiple parallel threads to call them and execute with different browsers. Haven't tried parallel browsers personally, but I suppose it should be possible.

OR

I haven't used it but I suppose Selenium Grid provides support for parallel runs.

Answer (score 0):

Use Python to write a simple .py script that uses Selenium, it doesn't have to be a test. Start each driver (browser window) and pass stuff between them.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.url = ”http://example.com”
user = driver.find_element_by_name("user").text
driver2 = webdriver.Firefox()
driver2.url = ”http://example.com/” + user
driver3 = webdriver.Chrome()
```